# What is the difference between git push and jekyll build for jekyll blog

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am creating a jekyll blog using [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/). In the instructions I see that there is a command to build the site using the command `jekyll build`.

However, I noticed that when I make changes to my code/post and perform a `git push origin master` the content and changes are uploaded automatically. This makes me wonder why I would need to "build" the site.

Could someone help me understand what the difference is? I'm currently trying to add Google Analytics to my blog and I suspect that knowing the difference between the two will help me get it to work properly. Thanks.

Comment: if my Answer doesn't help with the Analytics issue consider posting a new question with more detail on that.

Comment: Thanks @maxpleaner for the explanation. I got the analytics to work by just inserting it manually. Before I was using a jekyll-analytics gem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to turn a Jekyll app source code into a site you view, it has to do that build step to create the HTML that is served.

Github pages automatically does the build step for you after the code is pushed (if the repo/brach is configured for Pages).

So, you are right. It is not necessary for you to run the command.

The reason you may want to run it is to run the site locally (using your computer as the server). Or if you want to deploy it to some generic static host other than Pages. Or if you want to just view the final compiled site for some reason.